# The best solution to Find Memory leaks

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Test for Memory Leaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420599/how-to-test-for-memory-leaks)
>   [how to find memory leak in c++ code/project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261201/how-to-find-memory-leak-in-c-code-project)
>   [How to find a memory leak in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996498/how-to-find-a-memory-leak-in-c)
>   [Is there a good Valgrind substitute for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows)

I've got a lot memory leaks in my C++ program. What's the solution (program) to find them?

Comment: Don't use C++. Sorry, couldn't resist :-D

Comment: @Thorsten: No, the real snarky comment is "don't use `new`".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Test for Memory Leaks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420599/how-to-test-for-memory-leaks), [Is there a good Valgrind substitute for Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows)

Comment: Make your own Garbage Collector for C++ xD

Comment: Also, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6261201/594137) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/996498/594137)

Comment: [`ack --cpp new`](http://betterthangrep.com/)

Comment: Don't manage memory yourself; always use [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

Answer (score 4):

I like using valgrind. Assuming `g++` or `clang++`, compile your program with `-g` and try:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full ./your_executable
```

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to modernize your program.

1. Search your programs for `new` and `delete`.
2. Update your program to use smart pointers. Everywhere.
3. Introducing leaks after that is complete will be "pretty difficult", if you've done it correctly.

If you're on OS X `man leaks`, the leaks Instrument, or valgrind. You can use these to watch the leak counts drop as the program is modernized ;)

Answer (score 1):

For which OS?

On Linux based systems, Valgrind. Free.

On Windows based systems, Insure++, Purify.... many.